# spring integration TCP one way

Tags: java, spring, tcp, client, integration

I need to write a tcp client what only send the data ower tcp, and not waiting the response.
I tried it with gateway:

```
      <int:gateway id="TCPgw" 
                 service-interface="org.mypackage.MyClass"
                 default-request-channel="input"/>

      <int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="TCPClient"
        type="client"
        host="xxx.xxx.x.xx"
        port="xxxx"
        single-use="true"
        so-timeout="10000"
        deserializer="TCPDeserializer"
        serializer="TCPSerializer"
        ssl-context-support="SslContextSupport"

        />
      <int-ip:tcp-outbound-gateway id="TCPclientGateway"
            request-channel="input"
            connection-factory="TCPClient"
            request-timeout="100000"
            reply-timeout="100000"/>        


    <int:channel id="input"/>
```

This working now, but Still wait the response.

What I need:

- xml configurable (like above)
- no polling (as I show i the inbound-channel-adapter )
- just call a function like send(byte[]) to send the message.
- (the SSL support mandatory)

I read lots of tutorial, but found none what describe how to set up just a sending client.

I think, i need to use an adapter but I dont know how.
Thanx

Comment: You could try it with a ServerSocket that just listens to that TcpClient. That way you are not getting a response

Comment: I need to write a client, the server is out of my controll.